# Checking for duplicates in vector and count them c++

Tags: c++, vector

My target is to check for duplicates in vector and post them with their duplicate count. Example:

```
vector<string> vec{"words", "words", "are", "fun", "fun", "fun"};
// words - 2
// fun - 3
```

I have found nice solution, but I don't know is there any possible way to print counter:

```
vector<string> vec{"words", "words", "are", "fun", "fun", "fun"};
sort(vec.begin(), vec.end());
set<string> uvec(vec.begin(), vec.end());
list<string> output;

set_difference(vec.begin(), vec.end(),
               uvec.begin(), uvec.end(),
               back_inserter(output));

for (list<string>::iterator i = output.begin(); i != output.end(); ++i)
    cout << *i << endl;
```

Comment: What compiler are you using (which one and which version)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply keep a `map` that counts the number of words.

```
vector<string> vec{"words", "words", "are", "fun", "fun", "fun"};
map<string, int> words;
for(const auto& x : vec) ++(words[x]);

for(const auto& [k, v] : words) 
    if(v > 1) cout << k << " - " << v << "\n";
```

[**live wandbox example**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/PPjXYzP6PFANOsBU)

---

Note that I'm using a C++17 feature called **"structured bindings"** to destructure `words`'s pairs to `[k, v]`. If you don't have a C++17 compiler, you can use `const auto& p : words` and access the pair members with `p.first` and `p.second`.

Comment: I forgot we could now see C++17 in the wild :')

Comment: I got error in const in second for loop. Should I include anything. Says "Expression expected"

Comment: @TeodorKolev: I'm using a C++17 feature called "structured bindings". If you don't have a C++17 compiler, you can use `const auto& p : words` and access the pair members with `p.first` and `p.second`.

Comment: for(const auto& p : words) ok, where to put p.first and p.second?

Comment: @VittorioRomeo maybe you should mention it in the answer (present and future). Comments are transient.

Comment: @TeodorKolev Replace `k` with `p.first` and `v` with `p.second`. And read the [`std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) documentation, it would help you a lot getting used to the STL.